# Comparing multiple columns using python?

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, conda, where-clause

I am trying to compare multiple columns and assign the boolean value to a new column called `New Column`. Please find the sample data below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date1':['2000-03-01', '2000-03-02'], 
    'date2':['2000-04-01', '2000-02-02'],
    'date3':['2000-05-01','2000-03-02']
})
print(df)
```

This is my attempt:

```
df['New Column'] = '0'
df.loc[df['date1'] <= df['date2'] <=  df['date3'] , 'New Column'] = '1'
```

However, this is now working and giving me error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Why is this happening and how can I solve it please? This does not seem to be a problem in other programming languages but in python. Can anyone help me understand the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use & for condition.

Example code is here.

```
df['New Column'] = '0'
df.loc[(df['date1'] <= df['date2']) & (df['date2'] <=  df['date3']), 'New Column'] = '1'
```